# Iterate through two 2D lists to create a 2D list of matched occurrences

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to find the solution to this but can't quite get anywhere! I'm sure there's an easy way of doing what I'm trying to do that I don't know about.

I have two 2D lists, **a** and **b** (example below). You can see, for the majority of values, the position [1] in each A list matches to position [0] in the B list (e.g. 5158648.0 in list **a**3 matches 5158648.0 in list **b**3) - I've put the matches in **bold** in the lists below.

In other words, B is a bit long sequence, and A is in the same sequence, but only has certain values of B.

> a = [[1000002.0, 0], [1000004.0, 1000002.0], [5158670.0, **5158648.0**], [5158261.0, **5159627.0**], [5155371.0, **5158256.0**],[5258673.0, **5158648.0**]]
>
> b = [[1000004.0, 'TF'], [1000005.0, 'TF'], [**5158648.0**, 'FT'], [5158670.0, 'FT'], [5387625.0, 'FT'], [5158624.0, 'FT'], [5158623.0, 'FT'], [5158668.0, 'FT'], [5158589.0, 'FT'], [5158641.0, 'FT'], [5158640.0, 'FT'], [**5159627**.0, 'FT'], [5158261.0, 'FT'], [5158664.0, 'TF'], [5158293.0, 'TF'], [5158291.0, 'TF'], [5158289.0, 'TF'], [5158274.0, 'TF'], [5158258.0, 'TF'], [5158272.0, 'TF'], [5158270.0, 'TF'], [5158287.0, 'TF'], [**5158256.0**, 'TF'], [**5158648.0**, 'TF']]

What I want to do is **get the 'TF/FT' across from B to the correct position in A**.

This would be dead easy with a dictionary, BUT the complication is a value (e.g. 5158648.0) **could have both values in different positions in the sequence** ('FT' at one point, then 'TF' further down)... so, I need to say "*at this position in the sequence it has 'FT' but at this other position in the sequence it has 'TF*' - see in the example above where 5158648.0 is both FT and TF.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? The desired end product would be as below:

> c =  [[1000002.0, 0, 'N/A'], [1000004.0, 1000002.0, 'N/A'], [5158670.0, **5158648.0**, '**FT**'], [5158261.0, **5159627.0**, '**FT**'], [5155371.0, **5158256.0**, '**TF**'],[5258673.0, **5158648.0**, 'TF']]

Note, some values (here '0' and '1000002.0') do not appear in b at all, so I need to account for these.

I tried getting the lists to the stage where I had 2 lists of identical length of the matching values, then running through with zip() to transfer the values across, but the tricky bit was trimming the lists down to get those 2 identical lists, especially with the 2D aspect.

Thank you !

---

p.s. in case the context is helpful - each of the numbers is a street ID and the 'FT'/'TF' is a travel direction (hence why it could be one value or the other - it depends which way it's travelling)

Comment: Do you just want to find matches for the [1] index of the A tuple? Not for the first value? How would you mark a float that's both TF and FT?

Comment: Yep, just the [1] index value needs matching, but I need to keep that connection between a[0] and a[1]. A float can only be FT or TF in the one instance (it's essentially a direction that a street is travelled). 5158648.0 could be FT at one point, but TF further on. Hence the sequence/position is key.

Comment: Could you please add to the example (5158648.0,TF) to the end of B and what you expect to see in A?

Comment: Good point - done

Comment: Sorry for hassling you here, but C hasn't changed - looks like you just chose the first occurrence of 5158648.0. My point was we need to know how this affects the final list - do you have another pair at the end, or the first pair has a 'FTTF' string.

Comment: sorry Kabanus, thought I'd changed it! I've added that in there - we'd have another pair at the end, so the instances of TF and FT are separate (i.e. at this last position, we're 'TF'. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you're trying to do. As I understand it 'a' determines the sequence and the only order that matters in 'b' is between 'ft' and 'tf' values of the same value. Thus I would use a dict, with a list of available values by order (in your question you hint that you control how 'b' looks like):

```
b = {[1000004.0: ['TF'], [1000005.0: ['TF'], 158648.0: ['FT','TF'], 
      158670.0: ['FT'], 387625.0: ['FT'], 158624.0: ['FT'], 158623.0: ['FT'], 
      158668.0: ['FT'], 158589.0: ['FT'], 158641.0: ['FT'], 158640.0: ['FT'], 
      159627.0: ['FT'], 158261.0: ['FT'], 158664.0: ['TF'], 158293.0: ['TF'], 
      158291.0: ['TF'], 158289.0: ['TF'], 158274.0: ['TF'], 158258.0: ['TF'], 
      158272.0: ['TF'], 158270.0: ['TF'], 158287.0: ['TF'], 158256.0: ['TF']}
```

Then you just need:

```
for x,y in a:
    try:
       c.append((x,y,b[y][0]))
       b[y].pop(0)
    except (IndexError,KeyError):
       c.append((x,y,'NA'))
```

Comment: Kabanus, you've cracked it. That's what I needed. You're right, the order is in A so all that matters is what comes first (TF,FT etc.). That's a much easier way of doing it.

Comment: (p.s. in 'b' above the numbers are missing 5s at the start, adding those in it works like a charm :-) - thanks!